# jQuery: insert <base> tag by finding out the base url of current page

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, I would like to insert the base tag on the page I am on, but how can I get the `baseUrl` reliably?

```
$(head).append('<base href="' + baseUrl + '">');
```

My overall aim is to render a page using phantomjs and get the html output. however, when there's a relative image or css, it comes up as missing because it looks for `localhost/image/header.jpg` or `localhost/css/main.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use normal javascript to get the base URL. Split the `href` and you have an array of URL parts. Combine/reduce as needed and boom. Origin.

```
var path = window.location.href.split( '/' );
var protocol = pathArray[0];
var host = pathArray[2];
var url = protocol + '://' + host;
```